# React native - Change styles dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a dynamic menu that I created using a map method.

```
          {navigationOptions.map(option => {
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity key={option.code}
                  onPress={() => this.procedureOptionSelected(option.code)}
                >
                  <Text bold style={header.NavigationBarOption}>
                    {option.type}
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            })}
```

However, I need an underline when I press a menu option.

So let's assume, that I pressed the first option. So, in the first option, there must be an underscore.

But I don't know how to do this in react native.
Could someone help me with an idea?

Comment: `procedureOptionSelected` probably sets `option.code` to state, right? So in `style={header.NavigationBarOption}` you can check if the current option's code matches that value in the state and if so, add the underline style to the style object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `style` prop to `TouchableOpacity` and check if this is the selected button like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={{ borderBottomWidth: this.state.selected === option.code ? 1 : 0 }}
  onPress={() => this.setState({ selected: option.code })
>
...
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Also I guess you can use `this.procedureOptionSelected()` since you set that `option.code` in there too!